# HTML not displaying after ?> php closing tag

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

As the title says, after a php script for populating a dropdown list, the rest of the html in the page is not being displayed (the drop down list is displaying correctly). I've read here other questions about this topic and they said it's because of an error within the php, but I've checked my code and it's ok. Here's my code:

```
<select>
    <?php 

        $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="llenarDB"; // Mysql username 
    $password="abc45de89"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="Administrador"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="USUARIOS"; // Table name 

    $dbh= mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT Usuario FROM $tbl_name");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['Usuario'] . "</option>";
    }
    $tabla1= mysql_query($sql, $dbh) or die ("");

?>
</select>
```

Where did i go wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: a fatal error `or die("");` would prevent all further output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query probably failed. Look at this line

```
$tabla1= mysql_query($sql, $dbh) or die ("");
```

You just `die("")` without any notice. Try to change it to

```
$tabla1= mysql_query($sql, $dbh) or die (mysql_error($dbh));
```

and you may get the problem

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? have you checked an error log?

Comment: yes, at the top of the page I have: <?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>

Comment: And does the `</select>` output?

Comment: noup... anything after the ?>... I tried deleting the 'or die ("")' and everything displays but I think it's not a good solution

Comment: Everything works correctly? Do you see the correct data?

Comment: yes, I deleted the whole line $tabla1= mysql_query($sql, $dbh) or die (""); and now everything works fine :)

Comment: Well, it means there's something really wrong over here. You just deleted line which should have retreive data from database, so I can't imagine it all works fine. But nevermind :-)

Answer (score 1):

It means that your code thrown an exception at this line :

```
$tabla1= mysql_query($sql, $dbh) or die ("");
```

And because of die(); the script finished executing before closing tag without even displaying an error.

Put the whole thing in a try-catch block

```
try{
    $host="localhost"; // Host name 
    $username="llenarDB"; // Mysql username 
    $password="abc45de89"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="Administrador"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="USUARIOS"; // Table name 

    $dbh= mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT Usuario FROM $tbl_name");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['Usuario'] . "</option>";
    }
    $tabla1= mysql_query($sql, $dbh) or die ("");
} catch (Exception $e){
   echo $e;
}
```

it's a good practice anyway

Or you can use the `or die (mysql_error($dbh));` as mentioned in the answer above

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when you tell php to `die` the entire file stops loading (it's an alias of the `exit` command).

Instead of using die, if you want the result to load, try using exceptions, which are disccused more thoroughly [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) towards the bottom.

```
<?
try
{
  $connection = mysql_connect(...);
  if ($connection === false)
  {
    throw new Exception('Cannot connect do mysql');
  }

   /* ... do whatever you need with database, that may mail and throw exceptions too ... */

   mysql_close($connection);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   /* ... add logging stuff there if you need ... */

  echo "This page cannot be displayed";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move "select" tag for after connection, then you'll can see the errors messages, like this:

```
<?php 

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="llenarDB"; // Mysql username 
$password="abc45de89"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="Administrador"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="USUARIOS"; // Table name 

$dbh= mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
?>
<select>

<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT Usuario FROM $tbl_name");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value=\"owner1\">" . $row['Usuario'] . "</option>";
}
$tabla1= mysql_query($sql, $dbh) or die ("");

?>
</select>
```